# Gridview doesnt allow editing if give Column Names with Select New With ()

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I am using the following to data bind to a gridview in vb.net its work fine and can edit cells but when i declare columns names it doesnt allow me to edit cell values is their any reason to this thanks

```
    Dim bs As New BindingSource


    bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.dbContext.skechersDeliveries Where u.isprocessed = False Select u)

    bs.ResetBindings(True)
    dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
```

This is an example How I would delcare the column names instead of slect u I would have something liek below

```
       Select New With
            {
             Leave.Id,
            Leave.Leave_Month,
             Leave.Leave_App_Date,
            Leave.Leave_From_Date, Leave.Leave_To_Date, Emp.EmplName, Leavetype.LeaveDesc, Leave.Leave_Day
            }
```

I am using the following select

OrderNumber
  Dim bs As New BindingSource

```
    Dim cfglocation As Int16
    cfglocation = cfb.StoreLocation
    bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.dbContext.R3Delivery Where u.isprocessed = False AndAlso u.location = cfglocation
                    Select OrderNumber = u.ordernumber, BarCode = u.tagbarcode, Qty = u.qty, Processed = u.isprocessed, NotDelivered = u.isDelivered)




    bs.ResetBindings(True)
    dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs

    dgDeliverys.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
    dgDeliverys.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
    dgDeliverys.Columns(2).ReadOnly =true
```

column three is qtry and which should be changedable as you see their i stop at 2 but when i declare the column names above i can no longer double click and edit the datagrid directly

Comment: Please show how you are defining columns.

Comment: How are you declaring your columns

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have....

```
Dim bs As New BindingSource


bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.dbContext.skechersDeliveries 
                 Where u.isprocessed = False 
                 Select New With{.ID = u.FieldThatMapsToID,
                                 .LeaveMonth = u.FieldThatMapsToLeaveMonth,
                                 .......
                                 .Leave_Day = u.FieldThatMapsToLeave_Day})

bs.ResetBindings(True)
dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
```

Comment: that is what I am telling u is the way I am doing it but when i come to edit a cell item its no longer bound for inline editing the cell appears to come readonly

Comment: OK.... looking at your code it looks like the data is coming from several table is this right?

Comment: no just the one sorry that code was just off net to demostrate i cant give out the real table struchure as big company

Comment: @MMych see code changes to explain cant beleive this is so hard

Comment: Can you edit if you don't declare column names? If you can then use that method. In your datagrid define your columns (don't use AutoGenerateColumns = true) and in each column you define user HeaderText.